# Point a url to another ip

Tags: ip, web-hosting

I have a small website hosted in  aws server. I do not want to write a blog engine so I want to use wordpress in cpanel.

Lets say my blogs will show up in domain/blogs url. will it be possible to somehow show the blogs from the wp cpanel when user visits that url and if the user only visits domain.com then they shud be in the aws server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to keep the website with AWS and host your blog with any other provider.

You can do that via creating the subdomain like blog.domain.com.

1.Get [Wordpress hosting](https://www.accuwebhosting.com/web-hosting/wordpress) with blog.domainname.com and your web host will provide the IP address of their web server. 
2.Just go to DNS manager of your domain and add following A record.
blog.domain.com >> webhost's given IP address.